# RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (8) in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

when I try to run a pytorch faster rcnn code (from https://github.com/rowanz/neural-motifs), I get the issuse as follow

```
THCudaCheck FAIL file=/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1518238409320/work/torch/lib/THC/generic/THCTensorMathPairwise.cu 
line=21 error=8 : invalid device function
```

It arises when operate
    keep.append(keep_im + s)
where keep is a list, s is a int number and keep_im  is a torch.cuda.Longtensor

It's strange that, when I modify the code as

```
try:
    keep.append(keep_im + s)
except BaseException:
    keep.append(keep_im + s)
```

It return error in the try and then operates again in the except, and successes....

Anyone know what happen here?
I use python 2.7 + pytorch 0.3 + Cuda 8 + cudnn7.1, Titan XP in Ubuntu 16. Thanks

Comment: invalid device function errors usually mean that the CUDA code hasn't been compiled to be compatible with your GPU.

Answer (score 0):

You have to upgrade torch version.
**

> For me upgrade to torch 1.11.0  version worked.

**